# Java-Vaadin How to set Variable contain any type of field?

Tags: java, vaadin

Hello i am newbie in Java `vaadin` so my question is that i want to make a function that take any type of Field like TextField,ComboBox..etc and do some property on it and return it !
but i don't know what is this Variable that contain any type of field , can you help me ?
i am trying to do the following:

```
public anything Calculate(anything a){
  a.setValue("Test");
  a.setEnable(false);
  return a;
}
```

Comment: What is anything for a Type? Is it `Object`, or...?

Comment: it's the name of object that i am looking for to put any type of field in it

Answer (score 2):

Very high level: [`Field<T>`](https://vaadin.com/api/7.6.2/com/vaadin/ui/Field.html).  More useable to manipulate generic field stuff: [`AbstractField`](https://vaadin.com/api/7.6.2/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractField.html).  From there many of the fields from Vaadin itself inherit.

Comment: It is also worth pointing out that you can get this information by looking at a class' Type Hierarchy. You can access this in the Eclipse IDE by clicking the class name and then pressing Ctrl+T